# Block Ping Replies from Only One IP or Interface

Tags: networking, server

I'd like to have either the public adapter or public IP address on a web-facing server configured to not reply to ping requests.

I have an openvpn tap/tun adapter which I'd like to still respond to ping requests.

So far I've only found methods to disable responses to *all* ping requests, or to disable responses to ping requests from a specific IP address.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and how I'd go about it?

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 if that's useful information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use `iptables` like firewall you can add this rule `iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p icmp -j DROP` This rule will deny only ping on `eth1` interfce. If you wish i can make answer with all needed rules for `iptables` but you must say me witch port you wish to stay open from internet.

Comment: Rule for specific ip is `iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -d <your_ip_address> -j DROP`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! At the moment I only have tcp v4 ports 22, 80 and 1194 running services.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start

Delete curent rules and chains

```
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain
```

allow loopback

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

drop `ICMP`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -d <your_ip_address> -j DROP
```

or/and

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p icmp -j DROP
```

or

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

allow `PING` for rest

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
```

allow established connections

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

allow `SSH`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

allow `HTTP`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

allow `OpenVPN`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

default policies

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Save

```
sudo iptables-save
```

This is it. I think :)